# Is it safe to call timer callback method like this?

Tags: c#, timer, exception, async-await, autoresetevent

Please correct me if I have some errors in this logic (not some elegancy things like getting rid of constructor initialization and using Init method instead for Poll). I have not had experience with timer callbacks so far. The code is pretty self-explanatory, I hope. What confuses me a bit is some mix of async things (like connection client creation) and further code - though, I just reused IClient class, it's not mine):

```
    public async Task<WaitForLoanActivationDto> WaitForLoanActivation(string userName, string accountGuid, int timeout)
    {
        const int dueTime = 0;
        const int pollPeriod = 500;
        Poll<WaitForLoanActivationDto> state = new Poll<WaitForLoanActivationDto>
        {
            Client = await _rpcConnectionPool.GetClientAsync(userName),
            AutoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false),
            StartTime = DateTime.Now,
            Timeout = timeout,
            Parameters = new Variant[] { accountGuid },
            Result = new WaitForLoanActivationDto { Active = false }
        };

        Timer timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(WaitForLoanActivationCallback), state, dueTime, pollPeriod);
        state.AutoResetEvent.WaitOne();
        timer.Dispose(state.AutoResetEvent);

        if (state.ThreadException != null)
        {
            throw state.ThreadException;
        }

        return state.Result;
    }

    private void WaitForLoanActivationCallback(object state)
    {
        Poll<WaitForLoanActivationDto> pollState = (Poll<WaitForLoanActivationDto>)state;

        if (pollState.StartTime.AddMilliseconds(pollState.Timeout) >= DateTime.Now)
        {
            try
            {
                using (RPCReply reply = ResultHelper.Check(pollState.Client.ExecuteRemoteCommand(WaitForLoanActivationRpcName, pollState.Parameters)))
                {
                    pollState.Result.Active = reply[2].IDList["Active"].AsBoolean().Value;
                    VariantList statusList = reply[2].IDList["statuses"].List;
                    if (statusList.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var statuses = CustomerInformationConverter.GetStatusesList(statusList);
                        pollState.Result.Statuses = statuses.ToArray();
                    }
                    if (pollState.Result.Active)
                    {
                        pollState.AutoResetEvent.Set();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                pollState.Result = null;
                pollState.ThreadException = ex;
                pollState.AutoResetEvent.Set();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pollState.AutoResetEvent.Set();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would just forego the timer for a complete async solution using a Task.Delay loop for your polling. This would also remove the necessity for the AutoResetEvent and make the code much cleaner. Also, because of the AutoResetEvent and you waiting for it you are also blocking a thread and I guess it could stall your UI, which wouldn’t be the case for Task.Delay.

Comment: Yeah i must agree this code is fairly contrived, you are creating a statemachine, to `GetClientAsync` then starting a timer and blocking the calling thread while the timer creates new threads to do something-or-other, when that finishes, it lets the original thread continue. Seems like its been refactored from an older style of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys.
@ckuri, based on your idea I came up with the code below. I have not used `Task.Delay` though, because as I understood it creates delay even if the task is successfully complete - after it. The objective of my case is to run RPC method each `pollPeriod` milliseconds during `timeout` milliseconds. It the method returns `Active == false` - keep polling, otherwise - return the result. RPC execution time might take more than `pollPeriod` milliseconds, so if it's already running - no sense to spawn another task.

```
    public async Task<WaitForLoanActivationDto> WaitForLoanActivation(string userName, string accountGuid, int timeout)
    {
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        try
        {
            const int pollPeriod = 500;
            IClient client = await _rpcConnectionPool.GetClientAsync(userName);
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
            WaitForLoanActivationDto waitForLoanActivationDto = null;

            while (startTime.AddMilliseconds(timeout) >= DateTime.Now)
            {
                waitForLoanActivationDto = await Task.Run(() => WaitForLoanActivationCallback(client, accountGuid), cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                if (waitForLoanActivationDto.Active)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    await Task.Delay(pollPeriod, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                }
            }

            return waitForLoanActivationDto;
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }
    }

    private WaitForLoanActivationDto WaitForLoanActivationCallback(IClient client, string accountGuid)
    {
        using (RPCReply reply = ResultHelper.Check(client.ExecuteRemoteCommand(WaitForLoanActivationRpcName, accountGuid)))
        {
            var waitForLoanActivationDto = new WaitForLoanActivationDto
            {
                Active = reply[2].IDList["Active"].AsBoolean().Value
            };
            VariantList statusList = reply[2].IDList["statuses"].List;
            if (statusList.Count > 0)
            {
                var statuses = CustomerInformationConverter.GetStatusesList(statusList);
                waitForLoanActivationDto.Statuses = statuses.ToArray();
            }
            return waitForLoanActivationDto;
        }
    }
```